# Conversion in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What does this code do?

```
SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),
    DATEDIFF(mi,ThisTimeLastYear,TimeToday))/60))
```

I understand what the query is doing but why do I have to use Convert Decimal twice to make the statement work? I got the query to produce the result that I wanted but just want to know why as it came to me as a try before getting the desired result.

Comment: Basically, there is no real reason why the same two converts are applied to this, since second CONVERT actually convert first decimal into decimal (there is no reason to do this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because without both converts, you *first* perform `DATEDIFF_result/60` as an *integer* division, and *then* convert it to a decimal.

There are other ways to force the division not to be done between integers. Simplest would be:

```
SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),
    DATEDIFF(mi,ThisTimeLastYear,TimeToday)/60.0))
```

But, since the return type of `SUM()` is always defined to be a `DECIMAL(38,s)`, if you actually need control over the data type, it probably ought to just be:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),SUM(
    DATEDIFF(mi,ThisTimeLastYear,TimeToday)/60.0))
```